How Do I Setup an Existing Home Partition on Sprial Linux (BTRFS)?
Using Spiral Linux 12.231120 Budgie, single user desktop, single SSD. On first install, I used Calamares to put my home directory on a separate partition of my SSD (which I named "homepart"). Later, I wanted a clean install of the OS only. I booted a Live thumbdrive, and in Calamares I selected "Replace a Partition" and selected only the OS (root) partition only.
All went well, except how do I get the homepart partition to behave as before, where it is permanently mounted to the /home directory, and get the OS to use the "myuser" folder that is located there?
My partitions:
NAME    FSTYPE   LABEL    UUID
sda1    vfat     EFI      844D-26AF                                           
sda2    btrfs    root     9c92749f-4952-47ce-9d3d-be096b688163
sda3    btrfs    homepart bf98b404-5c23-4a6e-ac0a-de12bcad8214
sda4    ext4     sandbox  8f4eca4e-30da-4f64-8f78-b75c0c1a0e8e  

/etc/fstab:
# <file system>             <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=844D-26AF                            /boot/efi      vfat    defaults,noatime 0 2
UUID=9c92749f-4952-47ce-9d3d-be096b688163 /              btrfs   subvol=/@,defaults,noatime,space_cache=v2,compress=zstd 0 0
UUID=9c92749f-4952-47ce-9d3d-be096b688163 /.snapshots    btrfs   subvol=/@snapshots,defaults,noatime,space_cache=v2,compress=zstd 0 0
UUID=9c92749f-4952-47ce-9d3d-be096b688163 /home          btrfs   subvol=/@home,defaults,noatime,space_cache=v2,compress=zstd 0 0
UUID=9c92749f-4952-47ce-9d3d-be096b688163 /root          btrfs   subvol=/@root,defaults,noatime,space_cache=v2,compress=zstd 0 0
UUID=9c92749f-4952-47ce-9d3d-be096b688163 /var/log       btrfs   subvol=/@var@log,defaults,noatime,space_cache=v2,compress=zstd 0 0
UUID=9c92749f-4952-47ce-9d3d-be096b688163 /var/lib/AccountsService btrfs   subvol=/@var@lib@AccountsService,defaults,noatime,space_cache=v2,compress=zstd 0 0
UUID=9c92749f-4952-47ce-9d3d-be096b688163 /tmp           btrfs   subvol=/@tmp,defaults,noatime,space_cache=v2,compress=zstd 0 0
tmpfs                                     /tmp           tmpfs   defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0 0


Uhm just change the /home fstab entry accordingly? (Replace the the UUID and remove the subvol=/@home mount option; certainly you would need to e.g. reboot afterwards)

And for future reference:  When reinstalling in such circumstances you need to manually select all the required partitions. That includes the ESP, the root partition that can be the exact same but formatted, and, in your case, also /home.

Changed the UUID of the /home fstab entry to match my "homepart" partition and removed the subvol=/@home mount option. After reboot, I had to edit the prefs of my file manager (Nemo) so that the folders in the sidebar (Documents, Downloads, etc) worked as they should.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
